# JSP download from intranet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I need to read binary file from intranet http server and get it to download to public.

SCHEMA

intranet file server(Apache)=1 <-->Public http server(Apache Tomcat)=2<-->internet authorized user=3

howto release this without save to filesystem on server 2

Thanks for answers i am new on java.

Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use java.net.URL (or another http client) to read from 1 and then print it out (in response to 3).

(In Apache Http Server or Nginx this can be achieved using reverse proxy.)

Answer (score 0):

I can only think of two ways in this situation:

- Redirect the internet request to intranet.

In JSP page use:

```
<% response.sendRedirect("http://intranet_address");%>
```

or

`<c:redirect url="http://intranet_address"/>` using standard taglib.

In Servlet page use:

```
response.setStatus(302);
response.setHeader("Location", "http://intranet_address"); or just  

response.sendRedirect("http://intranet_address");
```

- Use a kind of proxy on server 2 to read from server 1 and send directly to internet user without saving to server 2.

I have never tried the first approach on an intranet, but I don't think it would work given the fact the intranet address won't be valid to the internet user.

Now we are only left with the second approach - using a proxy layer. The proxy function could be implemented in many ways: a simple one might be just a bean behind the Servlet to open URL to the file server 1, read file and send it through Servlet response stream to the user or maybe you can use some kind of embedded HTTPClient.

**Edit:** Since you are going to download binary file, JSP is not a good choice. It's meant to handle textual data. You need Servlet to do binary stream. You can set things like the following on your HttpServletResponse:

```
 resp.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
 resp.setContentLength(length);
 resp.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + filename + "\"" );
```

so the content will be send as an attachment with the name you set.